# Docker for Mac tutorial- overlapping export paths

Tags: macos, docker

I'm following along with [Docker's "Getting Started" tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/), and in the "File Sharing" section there are instructions for sharing files into a new container.  In the "Preferences > File Sharing" tab, I clicked "/Users" and then clicked the "+" button, then selected a directory that I wanted to add to my container and clicked "Open", resulting in the following:

[image]

When I clicked "Apply & Restart", I got the following error message:

[image]

Not sure what I did wrong.  The docs don't mention this error, and a Google search for "overlapping export paths Docker" didn't return any relevant results.  Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folder that you want to share is a subfolder the /Users. So it is already shared.

Comment: OK, so does this mean that adding a directory to the "File Sharing" tab does not automatically bind that directory to an image, but rather just makes it available for binding when you create the image?

Comment: Yes, adding to "File Sharing" you will be able to map those folder as container volumes.